# MERGE after checking the condition in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

[image]

In this If i deleted "aravind" the node "ramya" has to be connected to "sreepad". For that I written a query

```
MATCH (m)<-[:createdBy]-(n:Login{UserName:"aravind"})<-[:createdBy]-(z)
merge (m)<-[:createdBy]-(z)  
set z.createdBy=m.UserName 
detach delete n
```

Its working fine when the node has a tail. But not working on the end user (Suppose "prem"). How to write a query which works for both ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:
1) Get node for delete
2) Get parent node
3) Collect child nodes
4) Create relationships 
5) Delete node

```
MATCH (n:Login{UserName:"aravind"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)->[:createdBy]-(m)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[:createdBy]-(z)
WITH n, collect(m)[0] as m, collect(z) as zs
 FOREACH(z in zs |
    merge (m)<-[:createdBy]-(z)  
    set z.createdBy=m.UserName
 )
detach delete n
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Can you explain difference between collect(m)[0] as m & collect(m) as m in this case.

Comment: Collect(m)[0] take only one node because we have only one parent.